# Unexpectable "except" raise in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wrapper

Please help with python script. Python 2.7.
I trying to make some function for repeating action with error check.
So in function that I calling below  (lib_func) as I think, there is no error.
But "except" in repeater() raising any way.

If i don't use "x" in lib_func() - it works without error, but I still need put arguments in lib_func().

Sorry for bad english and thanks in advance for any help.

```
def error_handler():
    print ('error!!!!!!')

def lib_func(x):
    print ('lib_func here! and x = ' + str(x))

def repeater(some_function):
    for attempts in range(0, 2):
        try:
            some_function()
        except:
            if attempts == 1:
                error_handler()
            else:
                continue
    break
return some_function

repeater(lib_func(10))
```

output:

```
lib_func here! and x = 10
error!!!!!!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Where is `break` statement in your code? It is not properly formatted at least here in your post.

Comment: Your `lib_func` should return a function object but you are returning nothing which would return `None` by default. Which means your are trying to call `None` in `repeater` function `some_function()` where `some_function` is None.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong and repeater should be called as follows:

```
def repeater(some_function):
    for attempts in range(0, 2):
        try:
            some_function()
        except:
            if attempts == 1:
                error_handler()
            else:
                continue
    return some_function()

repeater(lambda: lib_func(10)) # pass `lib_func(10)` using lambda
```

I dont understand what you want to achieve, but the above code executes `lib_func(10)` few times in a for loop.

Alternatively, you can use partial:

```
from functools import partial    
lf = partial(lib_func, 10)    
repeater(lf)
```

Comment: yes, with "return" was mis copy

yes, with lamba it works!

and what I'm trying to achieve is repeatedly doing function several times and if limit is exceeded - raise exception

I think it is okay now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should be passing the function pointer not calling it like you are here

```
repeater(lib_func(10))
```

It should be

```
repeater(lib_func)
```

You can modify it to take a number as argument

```
repeater(lib_func, 10)
```

Your function should be

```
def repeater(some_function, some_value):
    for attempts in range(0, 2):
        try:
            some_function(some_value)
        except:
            if attempts == 1:
                error_handler()
            else:
                continue
        #the break statement makes no sense 
    return #why would you return the function as it is not doing anything!
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem of variable vs function.

`repeater` expects to be called with a *function* as parameter. So when you call `repeater(lib_func)`, all is fine : `some_function()` actually calls `lib_func()`.

But when you try to call `repeater(lib_func(10))`, python first computes `lib_func(10))` (returning `None` in above code) and then calls `repeater(None)` => giving exception because `None` is not callable !

If you want to be able to call repeater with a function with one argument, you should pass the argument to `repeater`. For example :

```
def repeater(some_function, arg = None):
    for attempts in range(0, 2):
        try:
            cr = some_function() if arg is None else some_function(arg)
        except:
            if attempts == 1:
                error_handler()
            else:
                continue
        break
    return cr

repeater(lib_func, 10)
```

Or if you want to accept a variable number of arguments :

```
def repeater(some_function, *args):
    for attempts in range(0, 2):
        try:
            cr = some_function(*args)
        except:
            if attempts == 1:
                error_handler()
            else:
                continue
        break
    return cr

repeater(lib_func, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. It helpful to. I will raise post surely when achieve more reputation)